# Call function expression in external module

Tags: node.js, express

How do I call the function expression "extractUserProgress" which is situated in an external module from server.js?

**EDIT**
I have clarified further what is happening in my code. 
I have a chain of function expressions in my module that follow from "extractUserProgress". The last function returns an array which is what I'm after.

```
//setGen.js (module file)

module.exports = function(app, db) {

 var extractUserProgress = function() {
      //Access mongoDB and do stuff
      nextFunction(x)

}
 var  nextFunction = function(x) {
      let y = [];
      //calculate y
     return y  // this is what i'm after

}

}


//server.js

const setGen = require("./setGen")

app.get("/setGen", function(req, res){
      //data here from select input
      extractUserProgress   //How to call from here?
      console.log(y) //array from module

    });
```

I have required the module in server.js but not sure how to export function in this scenario where the functions in module also needs to access mongoDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code as-is, you can't - `extractUserProgress` is not accessible, it's declared inside the exported function scope.

If you need it accessible, and also need to keep the exported signature, then you can return a hash of functions e.g.

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  ...
  return {
    extractUserProgress(...) {
      ...
    },
    // More functions
  }
} 

// Usage
const setGen = require('./setGen')(app, db)
setGen.extractUserProgress(...);
```

If you don't need to maintain the existing exported function, then you can export the functions as a hash instead

```
module.exports = {
  extractUserProgress(...) {
     ...
  },
  // More functions
}

// Usage
const setGen = require('./setGen')
setGen.extractUserProgress(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have clarified my code further. Would you mind expanding on the hashing approach "..." please as I'm still unclear about how this works.

Comment: @quietplace `...` is just for brevity, that's not to be taken as literal code in this example, it's my way of saying "you fill in the blanks". What part don't you understand? I figured the examples were fairly clear.

Comment: Sorry the ... threw me. In your first example you no longer use function expressions. So how can I call functions within the module if they are not defined? For example, the nextFunction(x) line in my code.

Comment: @quietplace the functions are defined, I'm using ES6 shorthand declaration - see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily if you change the structure of your exports a little.

```
const extractUserProgress = function (app, db) {
  console.log('This can be called');
  //Access mongoDB and do stuff
}

module.exports = {
  extractUserProgress
};
```

you can call this function from the otherside this way.

```
const newFile = require('./server');

newFile.extractUserProgress(); // you can pass arguments APP and DB to this function
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I will be able to connect to my mongDB in this situation since it will now be outside of the connect scope from server.js

Comment: Usually, we create the mongo connection at the start of the app. not inside a function. but in the global space. then it is easier to import MongoDB data Modules as well. why do you want to create the connection inside the function?.

Comment: I thought it would mess with the passport authentication, but perhaps I'm mistaken

Comment: when I remove extractUserProgress from the module.exports scope  the db.collection("testusers") within extractUserProgress function throws an error 'db not defined'. I think that's why I did it this way

Comment: I think the best way to connect to a MongoDB database from a node program is to use mongoose library( https://mongoosejs.com/  ). At first, you may see this as a headache. but it will save you from a lot of pain. create modules to represent your data entities. 
then load all the entities at the beginning of the programme. 
then you can access any model inside your function. just import the mongoose library in the file where you write your functions.